# Notepad++ regex searching for duplicated value in the same line

Tags: regex, notepad++

I'm currently searching for a solution to highlight all lines with the exact same value side by side in a single line of a huge textfile.

What the data looks like is:
000xxxxx 000xxxxx
002xxxxx 000xxxxx
000xxxxx 001xxxxx
000xxxxx 000xxxxx

I want to highlight all lines where the first value matches the second value (both are unknown). So the result of my example should look like this:
**000xxxxx 000xxxxx**
002xxxxx 000xxxxx
000xxxxx 001xxxxx
**000xxxxx 000xxxxx**

The number of spaces between the two values differ.

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: Do you always have a group of digits, followed by a group of letters, followed by at least one space, possibly followed by the first word?

Comment: You may use `^(\w+)\h+\1$`. Demo: https://regex101.com/r/mlWgAN/1

Answer (score -1):

If I'm understanding correctly and the 'x's are supposed to represent a string of spaces of unknown length, you can do it with a backreference:

```
(?<dup>00\d) +\k<dup>
```